# I can not find my phpmyadmin share

Tags: phpmyadmin

Well, i install phpmyadmin on my ubuntu server, but i can not find my phpmyadmin folder.

And when i try to make myip/phpmyadmin, appears 403 Forbidden.

I try to find in /usr/share/phpmyadmin, but the folder is completely clear.

I try to execute some commands but it dont work, and when i try to install phpmyadmin again, said that is already installed.

I think that i need to edit some config files, but i dont know where this files is located.

If someone can help me.

How i can fix it?

Thanks

@EDIT:

```
/etc/phpmyadmin
/usr/share/dbconfig-common/data/phpmyadmin
/usr/share/dbconfig-common/scripts/phpmyadmin
/usr/share/phpmyadmin
/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin
/var/lib/mysql/phpmyadmin
/var/lib/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Look for it with `sudo find / -type d  -name phpmyadmin` command from a terminal

Comment: I put the command, but i try to enter in this folders, and i dont have nothing.

Comment: I dont have nothing inside the folders.

Comment: Try running these commands to re-install it: `sudo apt purge phpmyadmin` then `sudo apt autoremove` then finally `sudo apt install phpmyadmin`